# Switch setOnCheckedChangeListener not updating display in Kitkat

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat

I have a problem with Switch in Kitkat. I have a screen which has a list view and a switch in its footer view. The switch is added to the listview as footer in onCreate event and then the listview is asynchronously populated in onResume event, using SmsListAdapter which extends BaseAdapter. I have added two toast messages to switch's onCheckedChanged event to indicate the current switch status (ON|OFF).

The switch works perfectly well in lower versions of android phones (4 to 4.3). But in Kitkat, it works initially well, when the screen is loaded. But if I lock and unlock the screen and try to switch it ON and OFF, I only get the corresponding toast messages from ON to OFF and vice versa. But the switch display is stuck with its status when I unlocked the phone. If I change the orientation of the phone, display is correctly updated. I have verified this with 3 different Kitkat phones (Moto G, Moto E and Karbonn Sparkle v). But a similar switch in another screen works fine under similar conditions but it is not part of any list view. Am I doing anything wrong? Someone please help me to resolve this issue.

```
public class Reminders extends Activity {
private boolean headerAdded = false;
DatabaseAdapter f_dbhelper=null;
Cursor f_cursor=null;
ListView f_remlist=null;
SmsListAdapter f_adapter=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminders);
    try {
        f_remlist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.reminders_list_1);
        if(!headerAdded) {
            //add header and footer
            LayoutInflater l_inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            ViewGroup l_footer = ViewGroup)l_inflater.inflate(R.layout.reminder_footer, f_remlist, false);
            f_remlist.addFooterView(l_footer, null, false);
            f_remlist.setAdapter(null);
            headerAdded = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        MySmsList l_mylist = new MySmsList();
        l_mylist.execute("start");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }
}
}
private class MySmsList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... l_params) {
        String l_status="completed";
        try {
            Calendar l_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM",new Locale("en","US"));
            String remDate = dateFormat.format(l_cal.getTime());
            f_dbhelper = new DatabaseAdapter(Reminders.this);
            f_dbhelper.open();              
            f_cursor = f_dbhelper.selectAllReminders();
            rowCount = f_cursor.getCount();
            f_adapter = new SmsListAdapter(Reminders.this,f_cursor,remDate);        
            f_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return l_status;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String l_result) {         
        try {
            f_remlist.setAdapter(f_adapter);
        } catch(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        showMyQuoteSwitch();
    }
@TargetApi(14)
private void showMyQuoteSwitch() {
    Switch switchQuote = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.my_quote_switch);
    switchQuote.setChecked(f_pref.getBoolean1("R.id.switch_layer_quote"));
    switchQuote.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
            if(arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(this,  R.string.reminder_on, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,  R.string.reminder_off, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }               
        }
    });
}

reminder_footer.xml:
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rem_quote_layer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    >
        <Switch
        android:id="@+id/my_quote_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/none"
        android:checked="true"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The issue is solved. Each time when the switch is toggled, setting the switch view to "Gone" and again to "Visible" solves the problem.